# CIFAR-10 pixelwise training with libSVM matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, computer-vision, libsvm

Training the 50000 training images with feature vectors of 32x32x3 = 3072 dimensionality is making my computer get stuck. Is there a work around I'm missing to use libSVM efficiently for multiclass SVM classification? A day passes and the SVM is still running for only one class in a one-vs-all training framework.

*I am aware that using pixel values is a terrible way of optimal classification, yet I still want to run this as a lower bound benchmark for a study.

Code:

```
clc;close all;clear all;

addpath(genpath('./libsvm-3.21'));
addpath(genpath('./liblinear-2.1'));

%load all images:
M1 = load('../Data/cifar-10-batches-mat/data_batch_1.mat');
M2 = load('../Data/cifar-10-batches-mat/data_batch_2.mat');
M3 = load('../Data/cifar-10-batches-mat/data_batch_3.mat');
M4 = load('../Data/cifar-10-batches-mat/data_batch_4.mat');
M5 = load('../Data/cifar-10-batches-mat/data_batch_5.mat');

M = [M1.data; M2.data; M3.data; M4.data; M5.data];
M_labels = [M1.labels; M2.labels; M3.labels; M4.labels; M5.labels];
M_labels_double = double(M_labels);
M_double = double(M)/255.0;
%M_double is the dataset of [50000x3072]
%M_labels_double are the labels and has size of [50000x1]

model=cell(10,1);
for i=1:10
    model{i} = svmtrain(double(M_labels_double==i),M_double,'-t 0 -c 1 -g 0.2 -b 1 -m 4000');
end
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense; the label vector and feature matrix are not of the same size so you should have gotten an error. Also, if you use linear kernel (`-t 0`) then liblinear will probably work faster then libsvm. Also(2), why don't you use the builtin multiclass classification capability of libsvm?

Comment: I just checked, and computations got finished, but it took more time than I had thought.